# http-proxy-middleware returns 404

Tags: reactjs, proxy, http-status-code-404, http-proxy-middleware

I have a React application and I'm adding the `http-proxy-middleware`.

My goal is to redirect all the requests to `/recipes` and `/users` to my new proxy middleware, so I added to the `app.js` the following lines of code:

```
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';

const setupProxy = () => {
    return createProxyMiddleware(['/recipes','/user'], {target: 'http://localhost:3001'});
}
```

But when I run, I receive an error 404.

The browser logger says

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /recipes,/user  -> http://localhost:3001
xhr.js:187 GET http://localhost:3000/recipes 404 (Not Found)
```

It looks like it completely ignore the middleware!

Without the `http-proxy-middleware`, but with only the `"proxy":  "http://localhost:3001",` statement in `package.json` the application runs without problems.

Any idea?

Comment: I also have this issue, has this been resolved? Any suggestions please?

Comment: Well, I resolved this issue by myself. 
I used a completely different approach: I defined `REACT_APP_APP_SERVER='https://www.yyy.com'` in my `.env` file, then I use that info into the code to create the reference address: `const { REACT_APP_APP_SERVER } = process.env;
const parms1 = REACT_APP_APP_SERVER + path;`

Then I added `CORS` to my application server: `const cors = require('cors')

router.use(cors())
`
It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed import to require. I don't know why but it worked.

```
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';
```

to

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
```